# How to aggregate data to different values in a lump

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
data<-structure(list(X2 = c(4L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 
19L, 24L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 14L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 0L, 23L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 
0L, 5L, 7L, 21L, 3L)), .Names = "X2", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

Let's say these are one minute values. And I want to aggregate them to 5-min, 10-min, 15-min and 30-min separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to do this separately to get the `mean`, it can be done in a loop with `lapply`, by creating a grouping index with `gl`

```
lapply(c(5, 10, 15, 30),  function(x) 
   tapply(data$X2, as.integer(gl(nrow(data), x, nrow(data)) ), FUN = mean))
```